# Using Conditional slot in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer-3.x

I was building a material design card element in polymer 3 es6 and wanted to only have `<slot>` tags when the attribute is set true.
This is my js code:

```
export class ACard extends PolymerElement {
  static get is() { return 'a-card' }
  static get template() { return `


<div class="card">
  <script>
      if ([[media]]) {
          <div class$="card-image">
            <slot name="image"></slot>
          </div>
      };
  </script>
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <slot name="title" class="card-title"></slot>
      <slot name="text"></slot>
    </div>
    <div class$="card-action">
      <slot name="action-link"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`


  }
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      media: {
        type: Boolean
      }
    }

  }
}

customElements.define(ACard.is, ACard)
```

This is my index.html:

```
<a-card media="true">
  <img slot="image" src="">
</a-card>
```

So when media attribute is set to `true` card-image div and slot inside it is returned.
Have to apologize because I'm new to javascript and may have serious syntax and logical issues in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Dom-if template

```
<a-card media="true">
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{media}}">
    <img slot="image" src=""/>
  </template>
</a-card>
```

image will display only when

> media=true